# How to narrow a generic type via passed guard function?

Tags: typescript, generics, type-narrowing

Let's consider `Opt` from [ts-opt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-opt) package (it's just a Maybe/Option/Optional) and `isNumber` to have a type guard (`(x): x is number => ...`).

Is it possible to implement (and how) method `someIf` in a generic way (working with arbitrary type guard, type-safe, without user needing to specify type which is already in a type guard):

```
type A = number | string;
const x: A = 4;
const y: A = 'y';
opt(x)               // Opt<number | string>
  .someIf(isNumber); // Opt<number> (Some(4))
opt(y)               // Opt<number | string>
  .someIf(isNumber); // Opt<number> (None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of achieving that (without having `someIf` as a prototype function) is the following

```js
type A = number | string;

const x: A = 4;
const y: A = "y";

const isNumber = (a: any): a is number => typeof a === "number";

const someIf = <T>(ot: Opt<any>, f: (x: any) => x is T): Opt<T> =>
  ot.caseOf(
    t => (f(t) ? opt(t) : none),
    () => none
  );

const ox = someIf(
  opt(x),
  isNumber
); // Opt<number> <- Some(4)

const oy = someIf(
  opt(y),
  isNumber
); // Opt<number> <- None
```

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-sea-q7zk0?file=/src/index.ts)

---

The idea is pretty simple. Fold over the optional value, if `none`, we have nothing to do. Otherwise, validate the wrapped value against the type guard. If the guard succeeds, simply return the value (with its type now narrowed down), else return `none`.